# Longest Common subsequence theorem in CLRS

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, longest-common-substring

In CLRS in the dynamic programming chapter, there  is a theorem about the longest common subsequence prefix that states the following:

> **Theorem** Let the $X=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m)$ and $Y=(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)$ be sequences, and let $Z =(z_1,z_2,\dots,z_k)$ be their LCS.
>
> If $x_m = y_n$, then $z_k = x_m = y_n$ and $Z_{k-1}$ is an LCS of $X_{m-1}$ and $Y_{n-1}$.

The theorem has two more points but I am interested particularly in the first point, I don't understand why we only consider $Z_{k-1}$ to be the LCS of $X_{m−1}$ and $Y_{n−1}$ and **not** $Z$ to be the LCS of all of $X$ and $Y$, if already the last element in all sequences match.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem is used to construct a recurrence relation for computing the LCS of $X$ and $Y$. The first point states that if $x_m = y_n$, then one possible LCS of $X$ and $Y$ is an LCS of $X_{m-1}$ and $Y_{n-1}$ together with $x_m$. This is one of the cases in the recurrence relation.

You ask why we are not considering $Z$ as the LCS of $X$ and $Y$. There is no need to consider this, because this is already assumed to hold in the premise of the theorem. Given that, we want to deduce *other* information, which will later enable us to compute the LCS recursively.

Comment: aha, so in the theorem premise it is assumed that Z is a LCS, so we don't need to prove that, we only want to deal with the prefix cases to build the recurrence relation ?

Comment: yes that's right, it's a recursive behavior, if  $Z$ is LCS of $X \; \&\;Y$, and last elements are matching, then $Z_{k-1}$ must be LCS of $X_{m-1} \; \&\;Y_{n-1}$, ok now i got it, thanks a lot.