# How do these additional cases fit into this Theorem about the optimal substructure of a longest common subsequence?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

[Theorem 15.1 (Optimal Substructure of an LCS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)

> **Theorem** Let the $X=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m)$ and $Y=(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)$ be sequences, and let $Z =(z_1,z_2,\dots,z_k)$ be any LCS.
>
> 1. If $x_m = y_n$, then $z_k = x_m = y_n$ and $Z_{k-1}$ is an LCS of $X_{m-1}$ and $Y_{n-1}$.
> 2. If $x_m \neq y_n$, then $z_k \neq x_m$  implies that Z is an LCS of $X_{m-1}$ and Y.
> 3. If $x_m \neq y_n$, then $z_k \neq y_n$ implies that Z is an LCS of X and $Y_{n-1}$.

[format copied from related post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/126202/longest-common-subsequence-theorem-in-clrs)

The above cases are intuitive and easily provable.

I do not understand additional cases not explicitly mentioned in the theorem:

What happens here:

$x_m \neq y_n$ and $z_k \neq x_m \neq y_n$

The above statement combines cases 2 and 3. Does that mean Z is an LCS of both LCS of $X_{m-1}$ and Y AND X and $Y_{n-1}$? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You assume $x_m=y_n$ and then $z_k \ne x_m \ne y_n$. How is it possible $x_m=y_n$ and $x_m \ne y_n$?

Comment: ya just saw that, that is contradiction my bad

Comment: What I am really interested in is combining cases 2 and 3. Z can be an LCS of −1 and Y AND X and −1. Then we must consider both of these subproblems.

Comment: $x_m \ne y_n$ and then $z_k \ne x_m \ne y_n$ is also repetition of assumption, $x_m\ \ne y_n$ two times?

Comment: I don't think so? I could say that or ≠ and ≠ 

Comment: You probably mean the case $x_m \ne y_n$ and $z_k \ne y_n$ and $z_k \ne x_m$. Then $Z$ is LCS of $X_{m-1}$ and $Y_{n-1}$. For example, X=(2,1,3,6,4) and  Y=(4,2,8,3,6,5), and Z=(2,3,6).  Here, $5 \ne 6$ and $4 \ne 6$.So Z is LCS of (2,1,3,6) and (4,2,8,3,6). But this case can be considered as one of the previous cases: second or third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_m = y_n$ then *any* longest common sequence must end with $x_m = y_n$. This is what the first item covers.

If $x_m \neq y_n$, then there are three types of longest common sequences:

- Longest common sequences ending in $x_m$.
- Longest common sequences ending in $y_n$.
- Longest common sequences ending in neither.

These are all the cases. There is no other case.